# Mongo DB - Only Let Documents that match a certain condition get analyzed by the next stage of the aggregation pipeline

Tags: mongodb

I have a collection with various documents but i am trying to match and group only a certain subset of documents that match a certain condition:

scanned: true

```
{ "_id" : "uqtkoew8fxkqhif7t2im1geb", "_class" : "mz.co.crunchtech.vtchill.domain.tickets.PrivateWithTablesTicket", "tableId" : "59bba43c77c82a7d95b2bef2", "scanNumber" : 2, "maxScans" : 2, "scanDate" : ISODate("2017-09-18T19:36:37.045Z"), "creationDate" : ISODate("2017-09-15T11:37:20.411Z"), "type" : "pwtbday", "numberOfPeople" : 2, "eventId" : "59bba42d77c82a7d95b2bef1", "client" : { "email" : "", "phoneNumber" : "258849901374", "name" : "Rui Cossa" }, "smsState" : false, "rsvp" : 0, "scanned" : true }
{ "_id" : "wklyuxdkljjccoqymc5xee58", "_class" : "mz.co.crunchtech.vtchill.domain.tickets.PrivateWithTablesTicket", "tableId" : "None", "scanNumber" : 1, "maxScans" : 1, "scanDate" : ISODate("2017-09-21T20:14:42.383Z"), "creationDate" : ISODate("2017-09-18T23:17:47.681Z"), "type" : "pwtbday", "numberOfPeople" : 1, "eventId" : "59bba42d77c82a7d95b2bef1", "client" : { "email" : "", "phoneNumber" : "", "name" : "Gildo zefanias" }, "smsState" : false, "rsvp" : 0, "scanned" : true }
{ "_id" : "fu6dblxi3zcotnxtqhiqik28", "_class" : "mz.co.crunchtech.vtchill.domain.tickets.PrivateWithTablesTicket", "tableId" : "None", "scanNumber" : 0, "maxScans" : 1, "creationDate" : ISODate("2017-09-18T23:17:47.988Z"), "type" : "pwtbday", "numberOfPeople" : 1, "eventId" : "59bba42d77c82a7d95b2bef1", "client" : { "email" : "", "phoneNumber" : "", "name" : "Rogerio Zandamela" }, "smsState" : false, "rsvp" : 0, "scanned" : true }
{ "_id" : "2veawo9d0vya7jegdiuv5yl0", "_class" : "mz.co.crunchtech.vtchill.domain.tickets.PrivateWithTablesTicket", "tableId" : "None", "scanNumber" : 1, "maxScans" : 1, "scanDate" : ISODate("2017-09-21T20:14:42.383Z"), "creationDate" : ISODate("2017-09-18T23:17:48.015Z"), "type" : "pwtbday", "numberOfPeople" : 1, "eventId" : "59bba42d77c82a7d95b2bef1", "client" : { "email" : "", "phoneNumber" : "", "name" : "Yuka" }, "smsState" : false, "rsvp" : 0, "scanned" : true }
```

Even though all of the documents above have a scanDate the aggregation below returns an error:

```
db.ticket.aggregate(
   [  {$match: {"scanned": true}},
      {
        $group : {
           _id : { day: {$dayOfMonth: "$scanDate"},hour: {$hour: "$scanDate"}},
           totalScans: { $sum: "$scanNumber"},
           count: { $sum: 1 }
        }
      }
   ]
);
```

ERROR:

assert: command failed: {
    "ok" : 0,
    "errmsg" : "can't convert from BSON type null to Date",
    "code" : 16006,
    "codeName" : "Location16006"
} : aggregate failed

How to limit the aggregation only to documents that match the condition of the match portion

Comment: *"Even though all of the documents above have a scanDate"* -- No they do not. The third document is missing the field. Hence the error. Either exclude the documents with [`$exists`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/exists/) i.e `$exists: true` or replace the field value with a default date with [`$ifNull`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/ifNull/). But your existing `$match` and other pipeline operations did not consider the field may not be present.

Comment: Hi There, Just checked the third document does not have the field :( ! Thank you very much it is now working with that query